# How to customize registration process in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I want to customize default registration process in Drupal 7. The registration process includes 3 steps:

1. Show some account types (in a page or form?). For example "personal", "business", "organization"... And users will choose their own account type.
2. Fill information into registration form. Each account type which users choose in step 1 has some corresponding fields.
3. Finish registration with an confirmation email or something else.

The registration process is similar to https://secure.payza.com/signup

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49582/how-to-customize-registration-process-in-drupal-7) questions

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I just want to get replying soon